# PL/SQL - Split the loop to load the bad data

Tags: oracle, plsql, error-handling

```
declare
   cursor c_data
   is
      select * from test_product_u;

   error_row varchar2(4000);
   v_errormsg varchar2(200);

begin

  for i in c_data
   loop
 begin
   insert into test_product_u_final (PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE_RAW, DATE_FORMAT) 
     values (i.PRODUCT_NO, i.CREATED_DATE_RAW,i.DATE_FORMAT);
  commit;
    exception when others then
    error_row := i.PRODUCT_NO ||';'|| i.CREATED_DATE_RAW ||';'|| i.DATE_FORMAT;
    v_errormsg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,64);
      insert into test_product_error_new(error_no,error_row_msg,errormsg_sql)
                                 values (ERROR_NO.NEXTVAL,error_row,v_errormsg);
    end;
    end loop;

end;
```

1 - The above code inserts all the rows irrespective bad or good into the error table. I would want to split the code to just put the good data in the destination and bad data into the error? Any help here.

When I split the loop the reference to the FOR loop is not there.

Sample data

```
Product_no  CREATED_DATE_RAW   CREATED_DATE   PRICE
1             01-JAN-16        01-JAN-16       55
2           03-JAN-16          03-JAN-16       null
```

Comment: This tries to insert into a table and, if there's an error, inserts into an error table. What should this do instead? What do you mean with "good" and "bad" data?

Comment: If they're going into the error table then they are getting an exception from the insert into the 'good' table, surely. How else are you defining 'bad'? What error do they get? (You know Oracle has its own error logging mechanism, right? Which would let you do a single `insert...select`, rather than a slow cursor loop with one-by-one inserts)

Comment: So if there is one bad record this inserts all the records(good&bad) into the bad table, I just want it to insert the bad records to the error table. The issue I think is I should close the loop earlier , but in that case I loose access to the 'i' in the FOR loop.

Comment: @Alex Poole : Yeah I am aware of the other insert method , this is just a code snippet I am trying to work the way I want it to.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Can you please post some sample data, explaining which data should be inserted, which should go in the erorr table and why this code does not do what you need

Comment: That isn't what your code will do. You've structured it properly so only bad records will go into the error table. Are you saying there are rows in the error table that have no error message shown; or they have messages you think are not correct? Maybe adding table structures and sample good and bad data will reveal the issue.

Comment: I have added sample data at the top , the price column is not null , but the record tries to insert null , I want only the second row to go into the error table. But currently both the rows go in.

Comment: Your code has `date_format`, not `created_date` or `price`? You still haven't shown the behaviour you describe. I've double-checked with your code and it inserts into both tables, with a mix of good and bad data.

Answer (score 3):

No need for PL/SQL or a loop here. You can use Oracle's error logging feature for this:

First create a table where the errors should be stored:

```
execute dbms_errlog.create_error_log('TEST_PRODUCT_U_FINAL', 'TEST_PRODUCT_ERRORS');
```

Then run the insert:

```
insert into test_product_u_final (PRODUCT_NO, CREATED_DATE_RAW, DATE_FORMAT) 
select i.PRODUCT_NO, i.CREATED_DATE_RAW,i.DATE_FORMAT
from test_product_u i
log errors into test_product_errors
reject limit unlimited;
```

---

- Documentation for [dbms_errlog](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_errlog.htm)
- Documentation for [log errors into](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#BGBEIACB)

Comment: I would also like to catch the bad values , would the above code catch the errors and the bad values which the insert tried to do.

Comment: @user3442679: yes the error log table that the package creates contains the error message and a copy of the complete row that created the error

Comment: Yes LOG ERRORS is very wonderful. But note that the log errors table created for you is missing some key info (like when the row was added to the table, who did it, where it happened in your code). I built a helper package to correct this problem. Check it out on LiveSQL: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CTS18A4BCWHLNR9X1OC3DR6CF.html